# Javascript: keeping ball within the circle animation

Tags: javascript, animation, coordinates

I have a program of a ball that follows the cursor on the screen, on a html canvas.

I also have a circle on the screen, I need to make this ball stay within the circle.

here is the current conditional keeping the ball within the canvas.

```
if(ball.x < 0 || ball.x > canvas.width)
ball.dx = -ball.dx;
if(ball.y < 0 || ball.y > canvas.height)
ball.dy = -ball.dy;
```

ball.x, ball.y are the x,y coordinates of the "ball" object instance. The ball.dy and ball.dx is the direction of the ball, and the "-" reverses the direction of the ball when it hits the outside of the canvas.

here is the circle code for the arc.

```
context.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 60, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
```

format:arc(x,y,radius, start, end, false)

how can I utilize the center point of the circle by not allowing it to move outside of it?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I could be completely wrong on this, but can't you just use the Pythagorean Theorem? `(a*a)+(b*b)=(c*c)`

The center of your canvas is 0,0

The radius of your arc is 60

Ball position is 29,-29

```
function isInsideCircle(ball,radius){
    var a=Math.pow(ball.x,2);
    var b=Math.pow(ball.y,2);
    var c=Math.sqrt(a+b);
    return c<radius;
}
```

With ball at 29,-29 = distance of ~41 from center (inside the circle)

With ball at 50,50 = distance of ~71 from center (outside circle)

Comment: While this tells him if the ball is outside or inside the circle, it doesn't help him limit the coordinates of the ball to be along the circumference of the circle.

Comment: I realize one can figure out what you meant from the context, but: `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` is not the pythagorean theorem, it's a meaningless equation.

Comment: @IngoBürk Actually the distance formula is derived using the Pythagorean equation.

Comment: @VivinPaliath So what? The pythagorean theorem states that (in a right triangle) the squared hypotenuse is the sum of the squares of the other two sides. It is a statement about triangles. `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` says nothing about triangles, nor does it remotely explain what `a`, `b` or `c` is.

Comment: @IngoBürk `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` **is** known as the [Pythagorean Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), and `a` and `b` and `c` are interpreted to be the sides of a right triangle with `c` as the hypotenuse. While in general an equation of that form can represent something else (like a circle), using it with `a`, `b`, and `c` is typically interpreted as the Pythagorean Equation. It's most certainly not meaningless.

Comment: It doesn't even make sense to call this a theorem since it is an equation, not a statement, and theorems are proven statements. I guess you have to have studied mathematics to be picky about this, and like I said: it can be concluded from context what you mean, so I'm not sure why you try to argue with something that I said right from the start. But it simply is not the pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @IngoBürk It is used interchangeably in common parlance, and the equation is a representation of the theorem. I know what theorems and equations are, but you can have a mathematical representation (or even multiple mathematical-representations) of a theorem in equation form as well. I wasn't trying to argue against the usage; note that I called it the "Pythagorean Equation" :). I was taking issue with your claim that the equation is meaningless. It isn't, because the distance formula is derived by *applying* the Pythagorean Theorem and the associated equation.

Comment: Let's not extend this discussion any further. I wasn't trying to attack the answer in any way, since, like I said, the context is enough to know what it means. I just said that it wasn't correct in terms of mathematics (not common parlance), but there's not much use in continuing this discussion at this point. I just felt the need to point it out since it was explicitly referred to as a theorem.

Comment: @IngoBürk Sure, no problem and I agree; a theorem and an equation are different.

Comment: Lol. Lots of comments.  When I learned this back in 7th grade it was the Pathagorean Theorem, so maybe I was taught it wrong 20 years ago.  I also didn't really include the details on the fact that you are finding the hypotenuse based on a imaginary right triangle derived from the center of the circle to the balls coordinates in relation to the x and y axis. I guess I could have included that...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to calculate the `x` and the `y` coordinates of the bound each time. The bound basically runs around the entire circle. This point is the intersection of the line between the center of the circle and the current `x` and `y` mouse co-ordinates and the circle. The limiting condition is that the length of this line does not exceed the radius of the circle. So if you are ever in a state where the distance between the center of the circle and the current `x` and `y` is greater than the radius of the circle, you will have to limit the `x` and `y` coordinate to be on the circumference of the circle.

The equation for a circle is:

```
x^2 + y^2 = r^2
```

Where `r` is the radius of the circle.

The equation for a line is:

```
y = mx + c
```

Where `m` is the slope and `c` is an offset. In our case we're going to assume that the origin is the center of the circle, so we don't have a `c` which means the equation is:

```
y = mx
```

What about the value of `m`? `m` is our slope which we can calculate from the rise over the run:

```
rise = ball.x - yCircleCenter
run = ball.y - xCircleCenter
```

Which means the equation for our line is:

```
y = (rise / run) * x
```

You can substitute values of `x` and `y` into the circle equation to figure out the `x` and `y` that lie on the circumference of the circle, which gives you:

```
x_on_circle = (r * run) / sqrt(rise^2 + run^2)
y_on_circle = (r * rise) / sqrt(rise^2 + run^2)
```

Assuming this was a function called `limit`, you can do something like this:

```
var distance = Math.sqrt(((ball.x - xCircleCenter) ^ 2) + ((ball.y - yCircleCenter) ^ 2));
if(distance > radius) {
    var limitedCoordinates = limit(ball.x, ball.y);
    ball.x = limitedCoordinates.x;
    ball.y = limitedCoordinates.y
}
```

Comment: @VivinPailiath you mean  `Math.sqrt(((ball.x - xCircleCenter) ** 2) + ((ball.y - yCircleCenter) ** 2))`. **^** In javascript is a bitwise operator, and is not used for finding power.